# "Custom Post Type Permalinks" plugin URL strcuture

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I've found this great plugin *Custom Post Type Permalinks* by a Japenese developer which is awesome at generating hierarchical permalink structures for Custom Post Types. Only I'm having an issue which I cannot get around and am looking for a solution.

I have a custom post type `classes` and a taxonomy `classes_categories` (ex: languages, technology, sciences...)

The links generated by WordPress for the 'classes_categories' look like this:

```
http://site.com/classes/class_categories/languages/
```

I would like them to be like this:

```
http://site.com/classes/languages/
```

Strangely, both of the URL's work but I would like WordPress to generate them without 'class_categories' in the URL.

I'm looking for a solution which would involve either plugin configuration, my taxonomy declaration parameters or perhaps a workaround with a hook or something (maybe parse the URL when they a being rewritten).

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to fix this by toying with my Custom Post Type and Taxonomy registrations.

In `register_post_type` properties:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'classes' ),
```

In `register_taxonomy` properties:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'classes', 'with_front'=> false ),
```

I now have a clean structure where `http://site.com/classes/` points to the post type archive template, `http://site.com/classes/languages/` points to the taxonomy archive template and `http://site.com/classes/languages/french/` points to the post template

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of Custom Post Permalinks.

The Permalink like

```
http://site.com/classes/languages/
```

is impossible.

Because, /languages/  is unable to determine term_name or post_name.

Sorry.
But  I want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Hiroshi, like I mentioned, I was able to achieve this with simple configuration. In the plugin options, I set the `classes` strcuture to `/%class_categories%/%postname%/`. Then in the registration parameters, I set the `rewrite` parameters as described above. DM me on Twitter @seb2point0 if you would like more info on how I did this.